# How to import basic functions like len() or help() in C++ with pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I'm quite new to pybind11 and I was trying to import/borrow simple Python functions like `len()` or **especially** `help()` inside my C++ code.

Note that I don't want to use pybinds`.doc()` inside C++ since I want to extract names and types of the parameters passed to Python functions.

I'm already familiar with:

```cpp
auto fnc = py::reinterpret_borrow< py::function >( 
    py::module::import( "sys" ).attr( "path" ).attr( "append" ) );
```

But I can't find any definition of how to import functions outside of specific python modules.

Comment: Those functions are also part of a regular python module called `builtins` https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html#module-builtins

Comment: Note that to do `inline formatting` it is preferable to use single backticks, even though triple backticks work. The former are easier to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @unddoch for mentioning the `buitlins` module.

Unfortunately `help()` is using `sys.stdout` by default. Therefore I switched to using `pydoc.render_doc()` to catch it as a string.

My working code looks like this:

```cpp
py::function helpFnc = py::reinterpret_borrow< py::function >(
    py::module::import( "pydoc" ).attr("render_doc") );
auto helpResult = helpfunc(pyExecute,"%s",0,py::module::import( "pydoc" ).attr("plaintext"));

std::cout << "Help in C++: " << helpResult.cast<std::string>() << std::endl;
```